# RGB light with case and cable for Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, led

We need an external light for a Raspberry PI. This light should already ship with a case. Also it needs to have a cable (about 1 m). It doesn't matter whether it's USB or is plugged directly in the hardware pins of the PI. This light should be able to display RGB light. Some SDK should be shipped with it (like a Python library etc.).